# Ignoring SQL 70001 Build Error in Azure CI Pipeline for SSDT Project

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

How can I configure my Azure CI pipeline for a SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) project to ignore the SQL 70001 build error and allow the pipeline to succeed even when this error is present during the build process

> TFS version -> 16.131.28106.2
>
> SSDT version -> 17.7.10.1
>
> SQL version -> SQL Server 2019
>
> VS version -> 17.7.4

Comment: 1. Can you ignore error `SQL70001: This statement is not recognized in this context.` when building this project locally? 2. Which task are you using to build your project in Azure DevOps? 3. Your project has this error because you are essentially putting DML code where only DDL code is allowed. This is an error in your project itself. Why not fix it but keep it?

Comment: 4. If you want to continue executing subsequent steps even if the build project task fails, you can use `continueOnError: true` in your build task. The pipeline result will be partially succeeded. See more info from [Task control options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-control-options).

Comment: Yes also getting this error locally (SQL70001). as we are using ALTER command in SP. It is also a valid operator  ..  
Also when I enable enable continueOnError: true It doesn't make a build artifact/Dacpac file        ..  
I am using Visual Studio Build Solution task for building project

Comment: Hi @Tahami Rizwan, thanks for your reply. As mentioned by Ivan, this is by design in SSDT. Visual Studio Build Solution task just calls msbuild.exe to build your project. It cannot ignore errors in the project itself. Therefore, it is recommended that you fix your project and do not use ALTER command. `continueOnError: true` just ignores the error of the current task and allows the pipeline to continue executing subsequent steps. The current task will still fail. It does not meet your needs for building artifact/Dacpac file.

Comment: ok Thanks for guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SSDT does not understand/support "alters" by design. Use CREATE only. SSDT will detect existing object on target server and alter it if needed automatically. This is not a warning, this is an error, build failure. And it affects not only the object with ALTER: this object does not get included into full project model (and into dacpac) and if any other object (another SP for example) will try to execute your "broken" SP then SSDT will say "sorry, there is no such object" (unresolved reference).